How to define the number of elements in a 2D Matrix C++
I'm unable to define the number of elements in a row in a 2D matrix.
I've attempted the code below.
int Matrix[3][6]{

// Row 1
{1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5},

// Row 2
{1, 2 ,3},

};

// Get number of elements in first row in matrix.
int Row1_amount = sizeof(Matrix[0]) / sizeof(Matrix[0][0]);


The code below returned the number 6, which is the predefined number of columns. I need it to return 5 which is the number of elements in Row 1 or even 3 which is the number of elements in Row 2.
I know it's easier to predefine the lengths using a single array, however that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Each row actually has 6 elements, not 5 (even though you explicitly initialized e.g. 5).

Arrays such as you are defining are not ragged. All rows are of the same length. Each row of the array you defined has 6 elements.  If you need a ragged structure with a different number of elements for each row, a 2d array is a wrong choice. Perhaps you should consider a std::vector of std::vectors. std::vector< std::vector<int> >

I would strongly advice you not to consider std::vector<std::vector> to be a matrix.   its memory allocation is not contigous and it fails to model the concept of a matrix. Your code becomes much more readable if you have a Matrix class (best reuse them from a math library!).  Also int Row1_amount = sizeof(Matrix[0]) / sizeof(Matrix[0][0]);  is how things are done in "C" not "C++". Give your matrix class a  "number_of_rows"  method (or if it is a square matrix, just size()).

@PepijnKramer I entirely concur in not using std::vector<std::vector> as a real matrix. I would not, however consider a data structure with varying length rows, as seems to be the OP's goal, to be an actual matrix.

@PepijnKramer I agree that std::vector<std::vector<int>> is generally a bad choice for a matrix. But it's not so bad for a very jagged one.

@wohlstad That's fair, but I like to use the type system of C++ too  so I would still wrap it in a matrix type. Avoids bugs and unintended use in large projects.. something about Hyrum's law ;)

@PepijnKramer I agree with that.

return 5 which is the number of elements in Row 1 or even 3 which is the number of elements in Row 2. -- You are letting the brace initializer fool you -- you are not setting the number of elements in a row by using { } and putting a comma-delimited sequence of numbers inside of { }.  In C++, not completing the set of items just leaves the rest of the values initialized to 0.  It doesn't change the fact that the row has 6 values.

@PepijnKramer I agree as I cannot use vectors at all. Or even anything that uses std. I'm using Arduino which uses a modified c++ so not everything is done the same as standard c++

Not being able to use STL is a myth. You can still dynamically allocate on arduino, you just need to be a bit more careful. E.g. only allocate your std::vector once (with reserve). In a way over allocating a static array eats up more resources.  Having said that, you should create a templated matrix class that can have your array inside of it

You cannot do this with arrays. Arrays have an unchanging fixed size, and do not store how many elements they have been initialised with. Instead you should use a data structure that does store how many elements have been added to it. In C++ this data structure is called std::vector. Use the size method to get the size of any individual vector.
Here's an example
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix = {

    // Row 1
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},

    // Row 2
    {1, 2, 3},

};

int main()
{
    int Row1_amount = Matrix[0].size();
    std::cout << Row1_amount << '\n';
    int Row2_amount = Matrix[1].size();
    std::cout << Row2_amount << '\n';
}

Output
5
3

